# ASP.NET, Linq and query, how to use result in my class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Please help with below

I have Model

```
public class TitleView
{
    public int Year;        
    public User User;
    public IEnumerable<Students> Student;
    public IEnumerable<Goal> Goals;
}



public class MyController: Controller
{
    private Db db = new Db();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User User = new User();

        Student Student= from a in db.Students where a.Name==User.Name select a;
```

> error on this line, that cannot convert type IQueryable to
>   Student.

```
        var test= (from a in db.Goals where a.StudentID== Student.ID select a).ToList();
```

> I can convert first line to List = .... ToList(); but then
>   appear error on this line - with  a.StudentID== Student.ID

```
        var model = new TitleView()
        {
            User = User,
            Student= Student
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

I know this is very simple

Comment: You need to call `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: You are trying to convert `Commitment` object to `Student` object ?? who your code compiles?

Comment: What you are asking is totally unclear. Also it seems like you are trying to get comitment object into Student type

Comment: Code is corrected, it was mistake. thanks. I received answer, or please help with question below in comments  :)

Answer (score 2):

For getting a single instance from a list, you will need to call `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

Read more about it here: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/understanding-single-singleordefault-first-and-firstordefault

Comment: Is it good practice to do like this? I mean 1. Receive result from query - convert to List. 2. Take First element from result and make again query ?

Comment: No that is definitely not good practice. You load the entire table and then take only the first one. It should be like this for example ```db.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == User.Name)```

Comment: Please could you proide next example 1. Query and receive some Data from one table. 2. Using this data to make 2nd query to another table ?